# jQuery Mobile Footer Flicker on Transition

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Whenever I load another page and see the transition *my footer flickers* (just the footer. It's `data-position=fixed`). It basically bounces down and soon thereafter is back to its actual position.

*Note: The second page being loaded doesn't have a footer. Even if it did the flickering still occurs. I haven't found a solution to this on stackoverflow...*

**I'm using the latest jQuery Mobile 1.4.**

Comment: how do you load another _page_?

Comment: Like this : `<a href="#two" data-transition="slideup"></a>`
The other page **#two** `<div data-role="page" id="two">` is embedded into the same HTML File, and consists of a Header and Content Area, but doesn't have a Footer.

Comment: add this css and see if the problem occurs `.ui-footer-fixed { bottom: 0 !important; }`. Also try other transitions, maybe it occurs with _slideup_ only.

Comment: The CSS doesn't seem to help. I tried different Transitions. The Animation occurs without the footer, and once the transition completes the footer kinda just **pops up**. This does only not happen when I'm using `data-transition="none"`

Answer (score 0):

If this is the same problem I was having, you have to make sure to put **data-theme="a"** (or whichever theme letter you are using) in the footer div.  The footer "forgets" the default during transitions.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-id="myfooter" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
```